# "Access Denied" as root

Tags: linux, router, sh, busybox

I have connected to my wireless router via `telnet` as root. It runs on linux kernel and has busybox.

```
/ # cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.4.110 (root@A23176683) (gcc version 4.7.2 (Buildroot 2013.02) ) #99 SMP Tue Apr 2 15:46:02 CST 2019
```

I can use some command such as `grep` `ls` `cd` `pwd` `cat`...

But for most commands I get

```
/ # echo $0
/bin/sh: Access Denied.
/ # chmod
/bin/sh: Access Denied.
/ # wget
/bin/sh: Access Denied.
```

Why doesn't root have all privileges, and which user does then (if any)

Comment: You might be root but the device might be mounted as read-only. Type `mount` to see if it is.

Comment: `mount` is disabled as well

Comment: It seems it blocks commands that contain some key phrase `grep "sendcmd 1 DB p UserInfo" /*` is blocked, but `grep "1 DB p UserInfo" /*` works. As well as `sendcmd 1 DB p DevInfo` works, but `sendcmd 1 DB p DevAuthInfo` is blocked.

Comment: There is a `/linuxrc` file, but its a binary, I did transfer it over telnet, but can't make it readable yet

Answer (score 0):

What is access being denied to?  Run "mount" and see the file systems which are mounted and see what their access permissions are.  Can you cd to /tmp and get the same behavior?

Comment: Command `mount` also thows `Access Denied`. Same thing in `/tmp`. Also `cd ~` takes to `/`. Although in `/etc/passwd` `root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/sh`

Comment: What does "env" or "echo $PATH" generate?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this info can be a bit useful. Have similar problem with my router (ZTE F660). If I do telnet from device which is connected directly to the router (LAN/WiFi) - I get full telnet access. But if I do remote telnet from remote device - I have such problems.
`Mount` shows this:

```
/ # mount
ubi:rootfs_ubifs on / type ubifs (ro,relatime)   
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)  
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,relatime)  
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,relatime,mode=600,ptmxmode=000)
/dev/mtdblock7 on /data type jffs2 (rw,relatime)
/dev/mtdblock4 on /tagparam type jffs2 (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /var type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=15360k)
/dev/mtdblock5 on /userconfig type jffs2 (rw,relatime) 
none on /mnt type ramfs (rw,noatime,nodiratime)
none on /proc/bus/usb type usbfs (rw,relatime)
```

`echo $PATH` shows this:

```
/ # echo $PATH  
/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

Both commands were executed on PC connected directly to the router, if I try do this remotely I see this:

```
/ # echo $PATH  
/bin/sh: Access Denied.
```